# hosting contentscript at remote location for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to make a chrome extension. There is some javascript code in contentscript. I want to put this code at a remote server and then in content script I am writing this -

```
<script src="path-to-remote-location/contentscript.js"></script>
```

But this approach is not working.

Is is possible to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), by default only local script and object resources are loaded.

> If you have a need for some external JavaScript or object resources, you can relax the policy to a limited extent by **whitelisting secure origins from which scripts should be accepted**.

That means you need to add the following to your `manifest.json`

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' path-to-remote-location; object-src 'self'"
```